# How to use assignment operator in mysql stored procedore

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

```
    DECLARE sp_ApplicationId char(38);
    SET sp_ApplicationId = UUID();

   IF(EXISTS(SELECT sp_ApplicationId = ApplicationId FROM aspnet_Applications WHERE       LOWER(sp_ApplicationName) = LoweredApplicationName)) THEN

               SELECT 'Application Name Already Exist';
```

I want to assign application id to sp_ApplicationId when the  condition is satisfied here i used = operator but it only compare the value.
  I also tried := operator but it show following error:

```
 Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= ApplicationId FROM aspnet_Applications WHERE LOWER(sp_ApplicationName) = Lowe' at line 14
```

Please help me out of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing  :

```
SELECT sp_ApplicationId = ApplicationId FROM aspnet_Applications WHERE       LOWER(sp_ApplicationName) = LoweredApplicationName
```

to:

```
SELECT 1 FROM aspnet_Applications WHERE       LOWER(sp_ApplicationName) = LoweredApplicationName
```

**UPDATE** if you are trying to assign the value of `ApplicationId` to `sp_ApplicationId` variable you can try:

```
SELECT ApplicationId INTO sp_ApplicationId FROM aspnet_Applications WHERE       LOWER(sp_ApplicationName) = LoweredApplicationName
```